# TypeError 1009 AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have looked through this code over and over and over but just cant seem to find where the problem is rooted. Here is the error message:

```
"TypeError: Error #1009: 
at com.senocular.utils::KeyObject/construct()[C:\Users\nti\Desktop\Ship game\com\senocular\utils\KeyObject.as:29]
at com.senocular.utils::KeyObject()[C:\Users\nti\Desktop\Ship game\com\senocular\utils\KetyObject.as:23]
at com.asgamer.basics1::Ship()[C:\Users\nti\Desktop\Ship game\com\asgamer\basics1\Ship.as:24]
at com.asgamer.basics1::Engine()[C:\Users\nti\Desktop\Ship game\com\asgamer\basics1\Engine.as:17]
"
```

It's certainly not in the KeyObject class since that's downloaded and not changed in any(and has worked before), but here's that snippet of code anyway(notice the markers where the lines are):

```
dynamic public class KeyObject extends Proxy {

    private static var stage:Stage;
    private static var keysDown:Object;

    public function KeyObject(stage:Stage) {
        construct(stage); <---------------------------------------------LINE 23
    }

    public function construct(stage:Stage):void {
        KeyObject.stage = stage;
        keysDown = new Object();
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed); <--- LINE 29
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
    }
```

Here are the parts of code that's causing the error:

```
  package com.asgamer.basics1
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import com.senocular.utils.KeyObject;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Ship extends MovieClip
    {

        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var key:KeyObject;
        private var speed:Number = 0.5;
        private var vx:Number = 0;
        private var vy:Number = 0;
        private var friction:Number = 0.93;
        private var maxspeed:Number = 8;

        public function Ship(stageRef:Stage)
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            key = new KeyObject(stageRef); <----------------------------- LINE 24

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
        }
```

and here's the engine class:

```
    package com.asgamer.basics1
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Engine extends MovieClip
    {

        private var numStars:int = 80;
        private var enemyList:Array = new Array();
        private var ourShip:Ship;


        public function Engine() : void
        {
            ourShip = new Ship(stage); <------------------------------- LINE 17
            ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

            stage.addChild(ourShip);



            for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
            {
                stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), stage.getChildIndex(ourShip));
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
```

I would really, really appreciate if someone would answer since this project is crucial to my final grades!

Comment: Your code is executing before Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event is fired that's why  stage is coming null. First addeventListener to this event and then in the event handler of this event write the code which is currently in the constructor of Engine Class.

Answer (score 2):

Instance of the Engine class is being constructed at the moment, when the stage property is still null. This means that the Engine class instance hasn't been added to the display list yet.

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#stage